# How to open in an Android project a new Activity from native

Tags: android, java-native-interface, augmented-reality

I make an augmented reality app in which I want when I recognize an image to load a new layout.

How can I Start a new Activity from a .cpp file?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Start a new Activity in your Android code, from the Native library? If you want good answers, you might want to clarify your question a bit. In Android you do not "call layouts" or "load new layouts".

Comment: Here is the specific question that I had made again with no response so far.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896076/how-to-call-a-java-method-from-c-in-android-to-display-specific-message.

Precisely Glenn.I want to start a new activity from native library.Do you know how can I do it please?